# Extracting fixed number of elements based on specific text and transforming to a data frame in python

Tags: python

How can i extract specific elements from a list as per the below criteria

```
mylist = ["aabc", "$2322", "$354", "lkgh", "rbus","hjguy", "$33","$77","kjlh","ghfd", "ytrwsd","$876", "$987", "abc", "efg" ]
```

I want to extract elements in the above list starting from the element with '$' sign till  +4 elements from '$' sign. The final output should look like below.

Tried extracting the elements with $ sign first with the below code

```
Key = '$'
text = []
for text in mylist: 
    if Key in text:
        print(text)
```

Got actual ouput as below

```
["$2322", "$354", "$33","$77","$876", "$987"]
```

alos tried extracting the indices of the elements with $ sigh and take the elements in between the indices with a difference more than one but this does not give the desired output.

```
indices = [i for i, s in enumerate(mylist) if '$' in s]
print(indices)
```

but not the desired output as below

```
mylist = ["$2322", "$354", "lkgh", "rbus", "$33","$77","kjlh","ghfd","$876", "$987", "abc", "efg" ]
```

Finally this list should be transformed in to a data frame like below

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your sample code?

Comment: @Hoog sorry I have not been able to come up with a code yet. Just trying to see whether its possible?

Comment: It is possible, I promise.  You should make an attempt and, if you run into issues, ask specifically about those issues.

Comment: yes I am stuck at the point where the logic needs to be put in to coding.

Comment: A simple combination of `for` loop and `if` blocks would be a great starter point if you're stuck.  Try that first and if you are still having problem, [edit] your question with your attempted code and actual vs expected results.  Until then, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt

Comment: @Idlehands I have edited my questions with my current attempt and actual output however seems like I'm still not getting the desired output. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop to iterate an index through `mylist`, and a nested `while` loop to keep incrementing the index until it points to an item that starts with `$`, at which point it adds the 4 items at the index to the output:

```
output = []
i = 0
while i < len(mylist):
    while not mylist[i].startswith('$'):
        i += 1
    output.extend(mylist[i:i + 4])
    i += 4
```

`output` becomes:

```
['$2322', '$354', 'lkgh', 'rbus', '$33', '$77', 'kjlh', 'ghfd', '$876', '$987', 'abc', 'efg']
```